# Having a problem with SwipeLoaded and SwipeLoading Conditions

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am facing an issue with SwipeLoading and SwipeLoaded Condition in my program. It is just When I am run only swipeLoaded condition. It will show only else part of the condition and if I run SwipeLoading Condition it will return only return part of the SwipeLoading Condition. Here is my code below.

```
import 'package:buis_talk/blocs/swipe/swipe_bloc.dart';
import 'package:buis_talk/widgets/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:buis_talk/models/models.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/home';

  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static Route route() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      settings: const RouteSettings(name: routeName),
      builder: (context) => const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: const CustomAppBar(
      title: 'Home',
    ),
    body: BlocBuilder<SwipeBloc, SwipeState>(
      builder: (context, state) {

             if (state is SwipeLoading) {
               const Text("swipeloading");
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
         else if  (state is SwipeLoaded){

           // ignore: unnecessary_type_check
          //  if (state is SwipeLoaded) {
          const Text("SwipeLoaded");

          var userCount = state.users.length;

          state.users[0];
          if(state.users.isNotEmpty){
            state.users[0];
          }
          // var userCount = (state.users).length;
          return Column(
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onDoubleTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/users',
                    arguments: state.users[0]
                    );
                },
                child: Draggable<User>(
                data: state.users[0],
                  child: UserCard(user: state.users[0]),
                  feedback: UserCard(user: state.users[0]),
                  childWhenDragging: 
                  (userCount > 1) ?
                    UserCard(user: state.users[0])
                    : Container(),
                  onDragEnd: (drag) {
                    if (drag.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx < 0) {
                      context.read<SwipeBloc>()
                        .add(SwipeLeft(user: state.users[0]));
                      print('Swiped left');
                    } else {
                      context.read<SwipeBloc>()
                        .add(SwipeRight(user: state.users[0]));
                      print('Swiped right');
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 8.0,
                  horizontal: 60,
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        context.read<SwipeBloc>()
                      .add(SwipeLeft(user: state.users[0]));
                    print('Swiped left');
                      },
                      child: ChoiceButton(
                        width: 60,
                        height: 60,
                        size: 25,
                        hasGradient: false,
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                        icon: Icons.clear_rounded,
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        context.read<SwipeBloc>()
                      .add(SwipeRight(user: state.users[0]));
                    print('Swiped right');
                      },
                      child: const ChoiceButton(
                        width: 80,
                        height: 80,
                        size: 30,
                        hasGradient: true,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        icon: Icons.coffee,
                      ),
                    ),
                    ChoiceButton(
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      size: 25,
                      hasGradient: false,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      icon: Icons.watch_later,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ); 
        }

        else if (state is SwipeError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('There are\'t any more users.',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3),
            );
          }
          
              
            else {
              return const Text('Something went wrong.');
            }
          }
        // }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code which I write for the condition that are SwipeLoading, SwipeLoaded and SwipeError.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:buis_talk/blocs/auth/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:buis_talk/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:buis_talk/repositories/database/database_repository.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'swipe_event.dart';
part 'swipe_state.dart';

class SwipeBloc extends Bloc<SwipeEvent, SwipeState> {
  final AuthBloc _authBloc;
  final DatabaseRepository _databaseRepository;
  StreamSubscription? _authSubscription;

  SwipeBloc(
    {required AuthBloc authBloc,
    required DatabaseRepository databaseRepository,
    })
    : _authBloc = authBloc,
      _databaseRepository = databaseRepository,
      super(SwipeLoading()) {
        on<LoadUsers>(_onLoadUsers);
        on<UpdateHome>(_onUpdateHome);
        on<SwipeLeft>(_onSwipeLeft);
        on<SwipeRight>(_onSwipeRight);

      _authSubscription = _authBloc.stream.listen((state) {
        if (state.status == AuthStatus.authenticated) {
          add(LoadUsers(userId: state.user!.uid));
        }
       });
  }

  void _onLoadUsers(
    LoadUsers event,
    Emitter<SwipeState> emit,
    ) {
      _databaseRepository.getUser(event.userId).listen((users) {
        print('$users');
        // add(UpdateHome(users: users));
        }
      );
    }

    void _onUpdateHome(
    UpdateHome event,
    Emitter<SwipeState> emit,
    ) {
      if(event.users != null) {
        emit(SwipeLoaded(users: event.users!));
      } 
      else {
        emit(SwipeError());
      }
    }
  
  void _onSwipeLeft(
    SwipeLeft event,
    Emitter<SwipeState> emit,
    ) {
      if (state is SwipeLoaded) {
        final state = this.state as SwipeLoaded;

        List<User> users = List.from(state.users)..remove(event.user);

        if(users.isNotEmpty) {
          emit(SwipeLoaded(users: users));
        } else {
          emit(SwipeError());
        }

      try {
        emit(
          SwipeLoaded(
            users: List.from(state.users)..remove(event.user),
        ),
      );
      } catch (_) {}
    }
  }

  void _onSwipeRight(
    SwipeRight event,
    Emitter<SwipeState> emit,
    ) {

      if (state is SwipeLoaded) {
        final state = this.state as SwipeLoaded;

        List<User> users = List.from(state.users)..remove(event.user);

        if(users.isNotEmpty) {
          emit(SwipeLoaded(users: users));
        } 
        else {
          emit(SwipeError());
        }

      if (state is SwipeLoaded) {
        final state = this.state as SwipeLoaded;
      try {
        emit(SwipeLoaded(users: List.from(state.users)..remove(event.user),
        ),
      );
      } catch (_) {}
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    _authSubscription?.cancel();
    super.close();
    }
  }
}
```

[This is the output after SwipeLoaded Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld8iJ.png)
[This is the output after SwipeLoading Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z92sz.png)